# facebook sdk 3.0 login with android activity class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

As previously used the login for the facebook for the fragment and that work great so with requirement change now facebook login with activity so,we have normal android button and on click of that the login dialog will appear for user interaction for giving username and password and when the login is sucessfull requesting with executeme to get user details.Every code is done but when click on the button dialog not appear but onsessionstate change the log showing output as

first show OPENING
than show LOGIN FAILED CLOSED

all the step require for login in facebook mentioned in facebook app development site is carried out and all the require class and meta data info is also given in andriod manifest file.

here the activity class for login

```
public class ResgistrationApp extends Activity {

    EditText username,password,name,nickname,email,phone;

    Button Registertauky,fb_connect;

    com.facebook.Session fbSession;
    ImageView user_image;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uihelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback sessioncallback=new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Sessionstate", ""+state);
            if(session.getState()==SessionState.OPENED)
            {
                makeuserdetailsrequest(session);
            }

        }
    };

    private Request.GraphUserCallback graphcallback=new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("FB RES", ""+response);
            Log.e("UID", ""+user.getId());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resgistration_app);

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.primus.taukyresigstration", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }

        uihelper=new UiLifecycleHelper(this, sessioncallback);
        uihelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_usernameone);

        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);

        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username);

        nickname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_nickname);

        email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);

        phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_phone);

        Registertauky=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Registertauky);

        user_image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.register_user_picture);

        fb_connect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.facbook_getinfo);

        fbSession=new Session(this);
        fbSession.addCallback(sessioncallback);


        //This going to register the tauky server

        Registertauky.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        //This button click going to connect to the facebook
        fb_connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            if(fbSession.isOpened())
            {
                fbSession=Session.getActiveSession();
                //do the fetching of user details..
            }
            else
            {
                fbSession=Session.openActiveSession(ResgistrationApp.this, true, sessioncallback);
            }   
            }
        });
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uihelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    class LoginretrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Session session;

        public LoginretrieveTask(Session fbsession) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            session=fbsession;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

    }

    protected void makeuserdetailsrequest(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Request user_request=Request.newMeRequest(session, graphcallback);
        user_request.executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        uihelper.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        uihelper.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        uihelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        uihelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Log.e("Sessionstate", ""+state); here showing LOGIN FAILED CLOSED.

and the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.primus.taukyresigstration"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.primus.taukyresigstration.ResgistrationApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/appid"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

so can any point me where i m doing wrong .Thaks for any reply

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the solution to login from the activity.

[Facebook sdk 3.0.1 is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729661/facebook-sdk-3-0-1-is-not-working-properly/16734283#16734283)

and this may also be helpful to you...

[Facebook Integration in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730848/facebook-integration-in-android-application/16734424#16734424)