# Facebook integration for login in android

Tags: android, facebook

Hi i am a newbie to android. I have a normal mysql login code and i want to integrate my app to Facebook login. Is there any easy way to do it. Should i have to download any sdk for this?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you need a facebook sdk. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

I'd prefer you to [follow this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) to connect/integrate your facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to download facebook sdk and you can integrate facebook as instructed in my answer-

[Facebook sdk 3.0.1 is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729661/facebook-sdk-3-0-1-is-not-working-properly/16734283#16734283)