# How to post a message in facebook using facebook sdk in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to post a message on  button click. I have tried reading developer facebook but unable to understand. please explain step by step process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post on facebook wall by calling the **publishStory()** Method given in following link..
[Facebook sdk 3.0.1 is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729661/facebook-sdk-3-0-1-is-not-working-properly/16734283#16734283)