# How to show facebook login on sharing if user is not logged in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, share

I'm trying to implement "share with facebook" functionality in my app but WebDialog crashes if session is not opened. Is there any built in possibility to request user login if session is not opened and show share dialog otherwise ?

Comment: You can use the following link to share on wall 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729661/facebook-sdk-3-0-1-is-not-working-properly/16734283#16734283

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    private void onFacebookClick2() {
            if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
                SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
                postToFacebook("Your text");

            } else {

                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, -1,
                        new FbLoginDialogListener());
            }
        }

or try this tutorial
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Unfortunately `Facebook` object is deprecated.